# Lambert involution

Tags: computational-mathematics, lambert-w

Let begin our discussion with the following curve 
$$ x=ye^{-y}.$$
Let choose a parametrization variable $z$ and we parametrize the above curve
$$ x(z):=ze^{-z}, y(z)=z $$ 
We find the ramification point of the curve that is when $\frac{\partial}{\partial x }x(z)=0$ that is when $z=1$. 
We are interested in the involution around the ramification point. That is the function $s(z)$ such that $x(s(z))  = x(z)$. So we did a shift of coordinate by 1 that is we move the ramification point at $0$. Hence the new parametric equation is 
$$x(z):=(1+z)e^{-(1+z)}, y(z)=1+z $$
Now to solve for the involution I put in maple 
$$x(z)=x(s) $$ and ask to solve in $s$ in terms of z it gives me the following function 
$$s(z)= -\text{LambertW}\Big(-(1+z)e^{(-1-z)} \Big)$$ 
when I take the expansion at $z=0$ of s(z) it give the following series

$$s(z):= -z+2/3\,{z}^{2}-4/9\,{z}^{3}+{\frac {44\,{z}^{4}}{135}}-{\frac {104\,{
z}^{5}}{405}}+{\frac {40\,{z}^{6}}{189}}-{\frac {7648\,{z}^{7}}{42525}
}+{\frac {2848\,{z}^{8}}{18225}}-{\frac {31712\,{z}^{9}}{229635}}
 .$$
which is the invloution at the ramification point $z=0$.

With the success of the above calculation, we want to find involution for the parametrised curve
$$x(z):= z{{\rm e}^{-w_{{1}} \left( q_{{2}}{z}^{2}+q_{{1}}z \right) }} y(z):=q_{{2}}{z}^{2}+q_{{1}}z. $$
If we put $q_2 =0,\ q_1 =1$ we get back our curve we started with. The ramification point for the above curve occur at the point

$$z=1/4\,{\frac {-q_{{1}}w_{{1}}+\sqrt {{q_{{1}}}^{2}{w_{{1}}}^{2}+8\,q_{{
2}}w_{{1}}}}{q_{{2}}w_{{1}}}}
 $$ 
and 
$$z=-1/4\,{\frac {q_{{1}}w_{{1}}+\sqrt {{q_{{1}}}^{2}{w_{{1}}}^{2}+8\,q_{{
2}}w_{{1}}}}{q_{{2}}w_{{1}}}}
  $$
I put in maple but could not find the involution around the ramification point. Is there any way I can find a series approximation of the ramification point. Also, it should satisfy that fact that if I substitute $q_2 =0, q_1 =1$ then it should give back the original ramification.

I am not an expert in LambertW function if there is a way to see the involution as some combination of LambertW function please let me know.

Comment: In the expansion of $s(z)$, you missed the constant term which is $1$

Comment: I don't think so involution fixes the ramification point so s(0) has to be zero. Also you can see the expansion in maple.

Comment: I am not using Maple but I was surprised that the $1$ was missing in the expansion of $s(z)$. That is all ! $s(0)=1$